# Accessing PFUser from a NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, forms, parse-platform

I am attempting to retrieve a `PFUser` which is inside a NSDictionary however I am not able to retrieve any data when I run my code. The PFUser in the provided dictionary is the User key. Here is my output:

```
// My dictionary
{
    hours = "10 Hours";
    location = j;
    notes = h;
    title = j;
    user = "<PFUser: 0x7fea4d578d90, objectId: h1WOITDkrF, localId: (null)> {\n    email = \"XXXXX@yahoo.com\";\n    fullName = Pradyumn;\n    username = Prnk281;\n }";
}

// Should be displaying the PFUser objectId displays null
2015-12-03 22:11:24.774 XXXXX[16176:816409] User ID: (null)
```

Here is my code as attempt to retrieve the objectId from within the PFUser,

```
-(void)savePressed:(UIBarButtonItem * __unused)button
{
    NSArray * validationErrors = [self formValidationErrors];
    if (validationErrors.count > 0){
        [self showFormValidationError:[validationErrors firstObject]];
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"FormValues: %@",self.formValues);
    PFUser *selectedUser = [self.formValues objectForKey:@"user"];
    NSLog(@"User ID: %@", [selectedUser objectForKey:@"objectId"]);
    [self.tableView endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: You should use `selectedUser.objectId`

Comment: Before getting a objectId from selectedUser why don't you print selectedUser in console to ensure that selectedUser has value. Do NSLog("Selected user : %@",selectedUser); (just to ensure value)

Answer (score 0):

When you make a query to get this data just add one line in the query.

```
[query includeKey:@"YOUR COLUMN NAME"];
```

You will get all the details of user in your current dictionary try this out.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my answer by following the two given comments.

First I checked to see if my selectedUser was a available value, which it was:

```
NSLog(@"Selected user : %@",selectedUser);
```

Then I did what @paulw11 said and used `selectedUser.objectId`